# Why does my controller displays {{message}}, like this instead of actual configured message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="js/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="LoginPage" ng-controller = "LoginPageController">
    <form action = "next.html" ng-submit="fun1($event)">
    username : <input name = "username" ng-model="un">
    <div>{{message1}}</div>
    password : <input type = "password" name = "password" ng-model="pw">
    <div>{{message2}}</div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to implement a basic login page using AngularJs, but however the browser doesn't display the actuall scope message, instead it displays the tag as {{message}}.

```js
//creating a module
var loginPage = angular.module("LoginPage",[]);

//registering the above controller to the module
loginPage.controller("LoginPageController",function ($scope){
 $scope.un = "";
 $scope.pw = "";
 $scope.message1="";
 $scope.message2="";
 
  
 $scope.fun1 = function(e){;
  if($scope.un.length == 0){            //checking for length
   $scope.message1 = "enter name";   //message 1
   e.preventDefault();
  }else{
   $scope.message1=""; // message 2
  }
  if($scope.pw.length == 0){
   $scope.message2 = "enter password";
   e.preventDefault();
  }else{
   $scope.message2="";
  
 }
}});
```

Comment: Where is your html page ?. Please add your view page.

Comment: Something causes angular to throw an exception or not bootstrap successfully at all. Please include any errors shown in the developer console.

Comment: Also, is the semicolon at the end of `$scope.fun1 = function(e){;` something that got copied over to Stack Overflow or it is like that in your code? If it's the latter case, that's your error.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i got the issue... the issue was in declaration of module and controller , i put "LoginPage", instead of 'LogInPage', ...it shoul dbe single quotes rather than double.

Answer (score 1):

The angular JS was not included properly in your code. Please add it properly. The working version is given below:

I just changed the following line:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to use the downloaded version of the angular library, please check your path and file name.

```js
//creating a module
var loginPage = angular.module("LoginPage",[]);

//registering the above controller to the module
loginPage.controller("LoginPageController",function ($scope){
 $scope.un = "";
 $scope.pw = "";
 $scope.message1="";
 $scope.message2="";
 
  
 $scope.fun1 = function(e){;
  if($scope.un.length == 0){            //checking for length
   $scope.message1 = "enter name";   //message 1
   e.preventDefault();
  }else{
   $scope.message1=""; // message 2
  }
  if($scope.pw.length == 0){
   $scope.message2 = "enter password";
   e.preventDefault();
  }else{
   $scope.message2="";
  
 }
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="LoginPage" ng-controller = "LoginPageController">
    <form action = "next.html" ng-submit="fun1($event)">
    username : <input name = "username" ng-model="un">
    <div>{{message1}}</div>
    password : <input type = "password" name = "password" ng-model="pw">
    <div>{{message2}}</div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```